# Через COM соединение в Delphi вызвать функцию 1С базы

Tags: delphi, 1с, com, ole

Нужно реализовать функцию на **Delphi**, которая вызывала бы функцию/процедуру в **1С** базе. Пользователь должен иметь возможность самостоятельно выбрать функцию/процедуру в базе, которую он хочет выполнить.

Реализовывается программа через **COM соединение**, версия **1C-предприятия 8.3**. Простейший код выполнения первой части условия выглядит примерно так:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  OLE_obj : OleVariant;
  answer : Integer;
begin
  OLE_obj := UnAssigned;
  OLE_obj := CreateOleObject('V83.COMConnector');
  OLE_obj := OLE_obj.Connect('File= C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\user; Usr = Admin; Pwd = 0');
  answer := OLE_obj.Получить_ответ('');
  if answeer = 5 then
    ShowMessage('Answer correct');
end;
```

Данный код работает стабильно, и в переменную `answer` записывается значение, которое возвращает процедура в базе. Код процедурки в **1С**:

```
Функция Получить_ответ() Экспорт    
    Возврат 5;
КонецФункции
```

Необходимо заменить ручной вызов процедуры `OLE_obj.Получить_ответ('')` на код, который способен получить строку `str := Получить_ответ('')` и как-то выполнить данное действие.

P.S. В **1C-базе** нужные функции находятся в глобальном модуле, с припиской `Экспорт` и установлена галочка `Сервер` в свойствах модуля.

Comment: В чем конкретная проблема то? есть название функции в виде строки, и надо вызывать такую у ole-объекта? дак `Invoke()` вам с этим поможет

Comment: http://www.1s-portal.ru/index.php/stati/common-questions/9-introduction/111-execute-111.html

Comment: @ teran А можно немного подробнее? Просто я с этим ни разу не сталкивался, а в интернете слишком завуалированно написано. Где мне взять IDispatch, PDispIDList и т.д.?